# Win7 set write permission for user without read access

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I want to set for user write permission without access to read what inside in folder. Is it possible?
User will be able to drag files in folder and cant look what inside.

Comment: This appears to be a system configuration question, not a programming question. Better suited to Superuser.com or ServerFault.com

Comment: I don't think this is possible without allowing the user to at *least* view the directory listing... What action would be taken if the user attempts to overwrite an existing file?  Couldn't he/she then infer the directory contents from this information?  Furthermore, if the user wasn't allowed to retrieve the file contents he/she just transfered, how would the user verify that the files were transferred correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Please note, I have not actually tried this, but it seems possible through the UI.

- Right-click on the folder and choose "Properties", "Security" tab, "Advanced".
- Click "Change Permissions"
- Select the user/group you wish to modify, and click "Edit" (or use "Add", if they're not already listed.
- Check the Deny box for "Traverse folder / execute file", "List folder / read data", "Read attributes", and "Read extended attributes"
- Check the Allow box for "Create files / write data" and "Create folders / append data".  They may need "Write attributes" and "Write extended attributes" as well.

Good luck - looks like one of those things that would be really easy to screw up...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if doing it with the configuration because you need the read permission in order to write, but what you can do os a script that takes all files in a folder and moves them in a folder in which the user has no rights. The script could be ran as a service directly at startup.

Comment: I think it was possible in previous Windows 2000

Comment: Then try using this: http://www.uwec.edu/Help/drives/permissions.htm , but as I sayed, write needs read.