# Enable Write Acess to Removable devices while restricting Read Access [Registry/GPO]

Tags: windows-registry, group-policy, windows-domain, acl

I'm trying to achieve this point:

- Disable Read Access to Removable Devices from Registry / GPO
- Enable Write Access to Removable Devices from Registry / GPO

### **What I've tried so far:**

- From gpedit.msc [image]

Then : **gpupdate /force** from cmd shell

**The Problem:**

- Now trying to paste a test file on the Removable drive to test if write access is granted, and the problem is described in the following animation

[image]

**Question:**
How to achieve this goal? enable write access and disable read access to removable devices on Windows clients via any available method.

Comment: Are you on a domain/using an active directory?

Comment: @NiallJones Yes! domain with AD, currently testing offline

Comment: You can't write without read access as writing requires reading the file system.

Comment: Your question might benefit from explaining **why** you want to achieve this seemingly-strange combination of 'write-but-no-read' permissions :)

Comment: From [this](https://superuser.com/questions/562421/win7-set-write-permission-for-user-without-read-access) page it looks like it's not possible, because write needs read as DavidPostill pointed out